# Is there a way to remove all the default autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: ace-editor

I've been able to add a list of suggestions to autocomplete but there is a large list of other suggestions as well.

Is there a way to get rid of the default autocomplete suggestions?

I'm looking at the source [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/autocomplete/text_completer.js) and [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/tree/master/lib/ace/autocomplete) and it doesn't describe anything about it. Here is what I have so far:

```
public function codeCompleter(editor, session, position, prefix, callback):void {
    var row:int = position.row;
    var column:int = position.column;

    if (prefix.length === 0) { 
        callback(null, []);
    }

    var testing:Boolean = false;

    if (testing) {
        callback(null, attributes);
    }
    else {
        callback(null, [{value:"addedToStage"},{value:"test"},{value:"test1"},{value:"adding"},{value:"added"}]);
    }
}
```

I tried setting the completers to an empty array but no effect:

```
editor.setCompleters([]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was on my end. The version I was using must have been outdated. I updated to a newer version and the following code clears the auto complete list:

```
// either line does it
languageTools.setCompleters(null);
languageTools.setCompleters([]);
```

**FYI:**
Using version 1.2.6+, 12.03.2016

PS Sorry to anyone looking into this. I will post version numbers in future questions.